# $(a \cdot b)\circ c = (a \circ c) \cdot (b \circ c)$ and $(a \circ b)\cdot c = (a \cdot c) \circ (b \cdot c)$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

> Do $(a \cdot  b)\circ c = (a \circ c) \cdot (b \circ c)$ and $(a \circ  b)\cdot c = (a \cdot c) \circ (b \cdot c)$ lead to a contradiction?
> Where $\cdot$ and $\circ$ are both binary operations who form groups.

(I try to use the minimal amount of group structure )
**Attempt 1**
“Direct Attack” using just the two statements to prove a contradiction.
$$(a \cdot b) \circ c = (a \circ c) \cdot (b \circ c)$$
$$=(a \cdot (b \circ c)) \circ (c  \cdot (b\circ c))$$
I continued doing this but it didn’t help.
**Attempt 2**
Using some group axioms.
the identity axioms don’t seem to help, my biggest suspicion is the axiom of inverses.
Can any of you help?
Note: I’m looking for answers with minimal added structure.

Comment: What is $(\cdot)$? What is the binary operation defined on $G$?

Comment: I assume this means that you have two group structures on some set, and you want to know whether or not the above equations are contradictory? Why do you think there has to be a contradiction? Also, in the question you say they do not have to form groups, but then in attempt 2 you talk about the group axioms?

Comment: If this operations are just some arbitrary binary operations, trivial one give example: fix some element $n$, and say $a \circ b = a \cdot b = n$.

Comment: Looks like $(A\cap B)\cup C=(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$ and $(A\cup B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$ to me.

Comment: Sorry, the question before the edit was unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $1$ denote the identity with respect to $\cdot$. Notice that
$$1\circ x=(1\cdot 1)\circ x=(1\circ x)\cdot (1\circ x),$$
so $1\circ x$ is an idempotent. The only idempotent in a group is the identity, so $1\circ x=1$ for all $x$, but this is a clear contradiction.

What this shows is that you only need to know that one operation distributes over another to obtain a contradiction to them both being groups. Indeed, this is why the additive identity in a ring is a zero for multiplication.

Edit: As Mark Kamsma pointed out, if the group has a single element then of course everything does work. So you have to exclude this literally trivial case. This is also why one of the axioms of a field is that $0\neq 1$, to stop the trivial ring being a field.

Comment: Being a bit nitpicky here, but there is one trivial situation where this is not a contradiction: if there is only one element which is the identity for both $\cdot$ and $\circ$. Other than that, good answer, I like the extra explanation!

Comment: @MarkKamsma That would mean that $1\circ x=x$ for all $x$, not $1\circ x=1$. Indeed, only the trivial group yields an example, so we have to assume that the object has more than one element in it.

Comment: Yes, but in that case $x = 1$. Let me just write it out: we take as set the singleton $X = \{x\}$. Then there is only one way to define the operations $\cdot$ and $\circ$ on $X$. That is, they both define the trivial group. Then the equations in OP's post clearly hold. But this is the only situation (which your answer essentially shows).

Comment: I think you edited your comment, or I did not read properly. Anyway, we seem to agree :)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you meant if the identities coincided. You meant if it is the trivial group. I agree.