# Non-trivial dual fields

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

> A dual field is a structure made out a set $S$, two binary operations $*$ and $\circ$ and two distinct special elements $1^*$ and $1^\circ$.

> $S \cup 1^*$ form an Abelian group under $*$ with $1^*$ as the identity. ($1^\circ$ is an absorbing element under $*$)
> $S \cup 1^\circ$ form an Abelian group under $\circ$ with $1^\circ$ as the identity. ($1^*$ is an absorbing element under $\circ$).
> In addition, they both follow [$(a \cdot b)\circ c = (a \circ c) \cdot (b \circ c)$ and $(a \circ b)\cdot c = (a \cdot c) \circ (b \cdot c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782893/a-cdot-b-circ-c-a-circ-c-cdot-b-circ-c-and-a-circ-b-cdot-c).

Do any non-trivial dual fields exist?
If not, can it be proven?
Note: the trivial dual field has two elements $\{0,1\}$ with the operations $\max$ and $\min$.

Comment: You meant to say 'dual fields', not duel which means fight (like in Star Wars). Please also change the notation as $\cdot$ and $\circ$ are hard to distinguish.

Comment: @TobyMak, any better?

Comment: That's better. Thanks for improving your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towards a contradiction, let's take $x,y \in S$.

From distributivity, we have

$$(1^\circ * x) \circ y = (1^\circ \circ y) * (x \circ y)$$

Since $1^\circ$ is $*$-absorbative, we see

$$y = y * (x \circ y)$$

Since $*$ has group structure (unless possibly $1^\circ$ is involved), we conclude one of the following:

- If $1^\circ$ is nowhere to be seen, then we can cancel $y$ from each side and get $1^* = x \circ y$. But since we assumed $x,y \in S$, this means $S \cup \{1^\circ\}$ is not closed under $\circ$, contradicting group-ness.
- If instead one of the above terms is $1^\circ$, it must be $x \circ y$. This is because we assumed $x,y \in S$, so neither can be $1^\circ$. But then we would have
  $y = y * 1^\circ$, which, by absorbativity again, means $y = 1^\circ$. A contradiction.

Thus, we must have $S = \emptyset$, leaving the trivial case as the only one.

(As a brief remark - if you don't insist on $1^* \neq 1^\circ$, $\{1\}$ with only trivial operations is another example. But that's even less exciting than what you called the trivial example.)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: If we “ban” the identities from the distributive laws, is there an easy contradiction not involving them?

Comment: I'm not sure... Once you start restricting axioms that used to be universally quantified, the resulting theories get unwieldy pretty quickly. With this question, I knew intuitively that it shouldn't be possible, so I set out to prove it. But I have little to no intuition for nonalgebraic theories, so I'm not sure whether to try and build an example or try to show there isn't one. It's a much more subtle question.